# Prioridade em uma notificação usando firebase

Tags: firebase

Estou utilizando ionic e tudo está configurado para mandar a notificação...

Queria aumentar a importancia dela porque ela não faz o barulho e nem aparece no canto superior como uma notificação padrão(como a de WhatsApp)

Como eu posso fazer para aumentar a importancia da notificação usando a API do Firebase Cloud Messaging

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que você esteja usando [o plugin do Ionic de FCM](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm).

[Na página da documentação](https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated#send-notification-payload-example-rest-api), há um exemplo utilizando o campo **"priority":"high"**:

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification title",
    "body":"Notification body",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
  },
  "data":{
    "param1":"value1",
    "param2":"value2"
  },
    "to":"/topics/topicExample",
    "priority":"high",
    "restricted_package_name":""
}
```

Para utilizar, basta usar alguma ferramenta que faça post, como o [Postman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heJmdX_djHs).

Comment: Na verdade não, estou usando o push notifications do phone-gap

Comment: nesse caso a propriedade se chama "importance". https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#channel-properties